# Xcode Singleton Undeclared Identifier amp

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, ampersand

I'm following a tutorial on creating a weather app for iOS. After a while, I've encountered an error which is  `dispatch_once(&amp;onceToken, ^{` use of undeclared identifier 'amp'.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?
This is the tutorial:
[Building a Weather Application](http://nscookbook.com/2013/02/ios-programming-recipe-15-building-a-weather-application/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial has an error in its formatting, and is showing an & as an HTML literal.  Change the code to `dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{` and you'll be golden.